# React code not responding to onKeyPress in React 16.

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

So I am trying to get a keypress to respond.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class ItemTextEdit extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            displayText: '',
            isEditing: false
        };
        this.handleKeyPress = this.handleKeyPress.bind(this);
    }

    handleKeyPress(event) {
        console.log(event.target.value);
        if(event.key == 'Enter'){
            console.log('enter press here! ')
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        const { displayText} = this.props;
        this.setState({ displayText });
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <span className="displayList">
                <span><input name="inputValue" className="inputValue" value={this.state.displayText} type="text" onKeyDown={this.handleKeyPress} /></span>    
            </span>
        )
    }
}export default ItemTextEdit;

ItemTextEdit.PropTypes = {
    displayText: PropTypes.string
}
```

I am not getting any kind of console.log response. I have tried to take out the extra methods in this component. I just want an input field to respond to onKeyPress. I have tried using onKeyDown and it still doesn't work. I saw a lot of posts answering that it needs to bind to the handler, but I am doing that in the constructor. Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I copied your stuff and it runs flawlessly on my machine... Where do you check the log?

Comment: I am just looking in the console in chrome dev tools for a console.log.

Comment: Same here, must be something else, the code works here and I do not see why it should not. Maybe you have a filter activated in your console? Try to debug the code, if necessary.

Comment: I have an onChange handler too, could one overwrite the other? Also I am not sure if I need to use event.key, event.keyCode, event.charCode?

Comment: better to usr charCode of Enter. I guess it is 13. You can do the check for that.

Comment: No, they should not overwrite each other. And the code is fine, the stuff with enter also works here. But does your onChange return true? That means, that the event is handled and will not trigger other functions.

Comment: no, just running a setState on displayText property.

Comment: My console.log is definitely not showing up for this component anywhere. I am starting to think this is a filter or something. weird. I put a console.log in componentDidMount and it does not show.

Comment: I added a console.log into a script tag outside of react, in my root file, and got it back. Something is weird about the console.log not showing up inside my react code.

Comment: I tired to run it in firefox dev tools and I do not see my console.log there either. I still see the script tag I added in my root file. I downloaded react dev tools, but I don't see a way to get console.log to show up there either. But it is cool to see the whole state of my project. Very weird on why I can't see console in the browser within react.

Comment: pleas let us know, when you figure out why, this seems weird :/

Comment: rookie mistake, wasn't updating on webpack in watch.

Answer (score 1):

Final code that worked:

```
handleKeyPress(event) {
    console.log("key is pressed");
    console.log(event.charCode);
    if(event.charCode == 13){
        this.setState({isEditing: !this.state.isEditing});
    }
}
```

This did not work:

```
if(event.key == 'Enter'){
```